# Setting the default Printer for windows using c#

Tags: c#, printing

I want to set a default printer for windows/ system setting on a button click. I want to click on a button and want that a windows dialogue should appear asking user to set a default printer. Right now I am using the PrintDialog for this but it changes the printer every time I click on the button. I want to set the selected printer as a default one  that should remain the same even if I close the application as well.

```
private void PrintSettingsBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  PrintDialog PrintDialog = new PrintDialog();
  PrintDialog.ShowDialog();
  PrinterName = PrintDialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `SetDefaultPrinter` Windows *API function*

```
   using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

   ...

   [DllImport("winspool.drv", 
              CharSet = CharSet.Auto, 
              SetLastError = true)]
   [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
   public static extern Boolean SetDefaultPrinter(String name);

   ...

   SetDefaultPrinter(PrinterName);
```

see

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162971(v=vs.85).aspx
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winspool/SetDefaultPrinter.html?diff=y

Comment: Can you please tell me which library I have to include?

Comment: You don't have to lnclude any library: DllImport as well as MarshaAs are in mscorlib; winspool.drv is a part of Windows so you've had already.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the project in Solution Explorer, choose Properties. Select the Settings tab,
add PrinterName setting.

In the code use the setting:

```
string PrinterName
{
    get { return (string)Properties.Settings.Default["PrinterName"]; }
    set 
    { 
        Properties.Settings.Default["PrinterName"] = value;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save(); 
    }
}

private void print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
    if (PrinterName != "")
        pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = PrinterName;
    if (pd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // Print

        PrinterName = pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Its giving me the exception The settings property 'PrinterName' was not found.

Comment: When I Right click on the Solution in SolutionExplorer its not giving me any kind of Settings. But when I click on one of my Project's folder then its opening the settings

Comment: You need the Project settings (WindowsFormsApplication1 or something like this), not the Solution settings. Take a look http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/193805