# Programmatically select a printer in PrintDialog

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

I have a Web Browser control in Windows forms. It loads a HTML file. I want to be able to give an option to the user to Save this as PDF file.

If the user has "CutePDF Writer" installed then I thought I can just select it programmatically from Print Dialog and Save it as PDF. I am showing the PrintDialog using Web_browser_control.ShowPrintDialog(). Is there a way to select a printer(CutePDF Writer in my case) programmatically in this Print Dialog without user intervention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure,but print dialog has printer settings related properties where you can define the default printer.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21178382/setting-the-default-printer-for-windows-using-c-sharp) is somewhat similar question asked in SO, the only difference being it was asked for windows. Neverthless, PrintDialog works in a similar fashion in web too.

Answer (score 5):

You can do like, this,

```
printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "YOUR_PRINTER";
```

Refer, https://andres.jaimes.net/65/how-to-choose-a-printer-using-c-sharp/