# Printing RDLC to a pre-defined printer without print preview

Tags: c#, winforms

In my C# winform app, I need to print an rdlc report directly to a printer which is not default, so I will need to specify the printer name/path and send it directly, can anyone refer to a good example? all what i found so far prints directly to the default printer, I will need to define the printer before printing the rdlc report.

the reason for this is because I have 3 printers connected to the PC, a bar printer, receipt printer, and kitchen printer. the receipt printer is the default one. so sending rdlc report to it is pretty easy as it's default, my concern is how to send the report to the kitchen and bar printers

Thanks

Comment: What is an RDLC report?

Comment: @LeeTaylor it's a Report Viewer "client" report report. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/using-the-winforms-reportviewer-control?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Note that the duplicate is in the [upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392779/programatically-select-a-printer-in-printdialog) : _printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "YOUR_PRINTER";_ - [More](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.printername?view=netframework-4.8#System_Drawing_Printing_PrinterSettings_PrinterName)

Comment: @TaW, Thanks helped alot, however it didn't asnwer my question, because im using RDLC report which is different than printDocument where you use graphics to draw your result

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms252091(v=vs.140)) seems to indicate that it uses  PrintDocument as well, no?  If it doesn't help I can reopen the post..

Comment: @TaW, Yes please do, Right it does use a printDocument however i'm using an RDLC with it so it's a different approach

Answer (score 0):

Add a class named LocalReportExtension.cs to your project:

```
    using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.IO;

public static class LocalReportExtensions
{
    public static void Print(this LocalReport report, string printerName)
    {
        var pageSettings = new PageSettings();
        pageSettings.PaperSize = report.GetDefaultPageSettings().PaperSize;
        pageSettings.Landscape = report.GetDefaultPageSettings().IsLandscape;
        pageSettings.Margins = report.GetDefaultPageSettings().Margins;
        Print(report, pageSettings, printerName);
    }

    public static void Print(this LocalReport report, PageSettings pageSettings, string printerName)
    {
        string deviceInfo =
            $@"<DeviceInfo>
                <OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat>
                <PageWidth>{pageSettings.PaperSize.Width * 100}in</PageWidth>
                <PageHeight>{pageSettings.PaperSize.Height * 100}in</PageHeight>
                <MarginTop>{pageSettings.Margins.Top * 100}in</MarginTop>
                <MarginLeft>{pageSettings.Margins.Left * 100}in</MarginLeft>
                <MarginRight>{pageSettings.Margins.Right * 100}in</MarginRight>
                <MarginBottom>{pageSettings.Margins.Bottom * 100}in</MarginBottom>
            </DeviceInfo>";

        Warning[] warnings;
        var streams = new List<Stream>();
        var currentPageIndex = 0;

        report.Render("Image", deviceInfo,
            (name, fileNameExtension, encoding, mimeType, willSeek) =>
            {
                var stream = new MemoryStream();
                streams.Add(stream);
                return stream;
            }, out warnings);

        foreach (Stream stream in streams)
            stream.Position = 0;

        if (streams == null || streams.Count == 0)
            throw new Exception("Error: no stream to print.");

        var printDocument = new PrintDocument();
        printDocument.DefaultPageSettings = pageSettings;
        if (!printDocument.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
            throw new Exception("Error: cannot find the default printer.");
        else
        {
            printDocument.PrintPage += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Metafile pageImage = new Metafile(streams[currentPageIndex]);
                Rectangle adjustedRect = new Rectangle(
                    e.PageBounds.Left - (int)e.PageSettings.HardMarginX,
                    e.PageBounds.Top - (int)e.PageSettings.HardMarginY,
                    e.PageBounds.Width,
                    e.PageBounds.Height);
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, adjustedRect);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(pageImage, adjustedRect);
                currentPageIndex++;
                e.HasMorePages = (currentPageIndex < streams.Count);
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, adjustedRect);
            };
            printDocument.EndPrint += (Sender, e) =>
            {
                if (streams != null)
                {
                    foreach (Stream stream in streams)
                        stream.Close();
                    streams = null;
                }
            };
            printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printerName;
            printDocument.Print();
        }
    }
}
```

Then call your reportviewr (passing the printer name as a parameter) like this:

```
this.reportViewer.LocalReport.Print("\\YourServer\YourPrinterName");
```