# How do I make Windows Server 2012 R2 reckognize installed printer

Tags: c#, printing, server, pdf-generation

I have a web forms **application that creates a PDF and sends it to the client**. It was all well and dandy until I uploaded the aplication to Windows Server 2012 R2. The problem might be some printer settings on the server (this is my first time working with a server).

The problem is Server 2012 doesn't support Windows Print to PDF, which I used on local machine and it worked great.

I gave a shot to **CutePDF Writer**: installed it and set it to **default** printer in **Printers and devices**. When I run the application, I get the following error:

```
System.Drawing.Printing.InvalidPrinterException: No printers are installed
```

I tried this and it generates the PDF but fails and I get an error when I try to open the PDF:

```
PrintDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "CutePDF Writer";
```

This line returns "true":

```
PrintDocument.PrinterSettings.IsDefaultPrinter
```

while this line returns "Default printer is not set.":

```
PrintDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName
```

I gave a shot with this, but returns "false":
[Setting the default Printer for windows using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21178382/setting-the-default-printer-for-windows-using-c-sharp)

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is trying a different approach. I shouldn't have tried working with the virtual printer (i haven't found a way to make it work).

To create a PDF from code, the best way is using iTextSharp.dll. With that you need a handful of code. Yes, I had to implement the report-creating and printing logic all over again, but it was actually easyer than the previous approach. iText is pretty straightforward and easy to use!